# complex mysql select query 6

Tags: mysql, select

I have table with 2 columns: w_id(word id) and txt_id(text id)

for example i have this values:

```
-----------------
| w_id  | txt_id |
-----------------
| 150  |   7    |
-----------------
| 151  |   7    |
-----------------
| 152  |   7    |
-----------------
| 152  |   7    |
-----------------
| 151  |   8    |
-----------------
| 160  |   8    |
-----------------
| 165  |   8    |
-----------------
```

I want to get w_id list witch is ONLY in spesific text
for this table if i want to get words for text 7 it will be 150 and 152.

I need your help to write this query. 
i am still thinking now to solve this problem myself.
this table can be very big. milions of rows. 
so i need to write it cearfully

i try this but this is wrong: this query gives me only 150, not 152. becouse it is twice in 7 text:

```
  SELECT w_id
  FROM tablename
  WHERE w_id
  IN (
    SELECT w_id
    FROM tablename
    WHERE txt_id =  '7'
    GROUP BY w_id
  )
  GROUP BY w_id
  HAVING COUNT(w_id) = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  w_id
FROM    tableName a
WHERE   txt_id = 7 AND
        NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    tableName b
            WHERE   a.w_id = b.w_id AND
                    txt_id <> 7
        )
GROUP   BY w_id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ac82/2)

you can also do it using `LEFT JOIN`,

```
SELECT  a.w_id
FROM    tableName a
        LEFT JOIN tableName b
            ON a.w_id = b.w_id AND
                b.txt_id <> 7
WHERE   b.w_id IS  NULL
GROUP   BY a.w_id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ac82/10)

Comment: witch one will be fast?

Comment: with composite index on the column, both have the same performance. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c821/1

Answer (score -1):

can you give more details?

i may get the same SQL as bfavaretto's base on your question.

and also:

i think if we use

```
SELECT DISTINCT w_id
FROM your_table_name
WHERE txt_id = 7
```

the result will be 150 151 152

Comment: I made the same mistake and just deleted my answer. `151` shouldn't be in the results.